# Label layer name

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, labeling, features

How can I find out the names of the layers that I can put in this example? I want to show labels with names of cities in my map. I'm using GeoServer.

```
var wms_layer_labels = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
'Location Labels',
'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
{layers: 'clabel,ctylabel,statelabel',
transparent: true},
{opacity: .5}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is requesting data from a WMS service. According to the WMS standard, you can get information about the capabilities of the WMS Service, by calling the GetCapabilities operation. You usualy do this, by requesting the following URL: `http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?request=getcapabilities&service=wms`

You will get an XML Document, which details all the Capabilities of this Service.

I'll like to draw your attention to the `<layer>` tag, which details the various layers that this service contains. You will find the various layers, and the names that you need to provide, and use in OpenLayers.